# SQL Server 2008 LIKE query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to use `LIKE` query to select some specific word just like `UU1`.

I use

```
SELECT UniID FROM MasterCustomer  where (UniID like '%uu1%' )
```

But it also returns a row which contains `UU11`.

How can I modify my query to select only `UU1`?

My table contains values like

```
UU1-UU7-UU5
UU2-UU1
UU3-UU1
UU31-UU14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT UniID 
FROM MasterCustomer  
WHERE (UniID like '%uu1' ) OR (UniID like '%uu1-%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

`like '%uu1-%' or like '%uu1 %'`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
WHERE UnitID + '-' LIKE '%uu1-%'
```